# Posting lists in your model back to the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model, listbox

I have not been able to find a good example of a model that contains a list that you pass to your view, then pass it back to the controller when the user posts.  I have lots of examples of passing back a 'selected' item in a listboxfor, but no example where I can persist the entire list in the model back to the controller.

I have searched far and wide and have come up short.  If someone can point me to a good example, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: hmm.. I responded to your last posting as well - no comments, no vote. may want to make sure you follow up on postings.

Comment: Are you able to extract your ListBox as `string[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your items are in inputs that will get posted back to the server and in sequential order - see:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Also - you could retrieve your own objects and send them over in a call to jQuery.post as your data parameter as well.

Comment: Thank you Adam.  I was hoping that a ListBoxFor control would persist back my list to the controller in the model, much like other HTML controls in my view.  I'm kind of surprised that I have to stuff each item in my list somewhere in order for them to post back to my controller (they are items in the list afterall).  I think I will use jQuery like you suggested.  Thanks Again.

Comment: This is the behavior I am looking for.  It uses a javascript library called Knockout that helps bind data on the client.   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/MVC2_DataBinding_Knockout.aspx?display=Mobile

Comment: you dont have to stuff it into anything as long as it exists in controls that are posted as part of the html spec, otherwise you have to manually do it